# BizUnit web service test - setting MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, bizunit

I'm testing one of the wcf services published with BizTalk with biz unit, and using following code,

```
 WebServiceStep wsStep = new WebServiceStep();
 wsStep.ServiceUrl = //service url;
 wsStep.FailOnError = true;
 wsStep.Action = //service method name;

 wsStep.RequestBody = new FileDataLoader() { FilePath = "request.xml"); 
 testCase.ExecutionSteps.Add(wsStep);
```

The given method usually return a lot of data which exceeds the maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536), the problem is how can I set the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` in above test code?

Answer (score 0):

The framework doesn't seem to expose that property by default, but you could add it in pretty easily.  Copy the code from WebServiceStep.cs into your project, and find following block:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
```

If you want the max size to be 10MB, you'd want to add something like:

```
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000000;
```

You could add a property to the class to make this configurable if desired - that'd be slightly more involved (but not terribly difficult).

Don't forget to rename the class and alter the namespace to your project so that you can access it from your own tests....